# List of recursive generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic interface which needs to be have its type as a generic parameter:

```
interface Base<X extends Base<X>> {
    X foo();
}
class Derived implements Base<Derived> {
    public Derived foo() { ... }
    public Derived bar() { ... }
}
class Derived2 implements Base<Derived2> {
    public Derived2 foo() { ... }
    public void quz() { ... }
}
```

I have another class which uses this interface as a generic parameter.

```
interface Policy<B extends Base<B>> {
  B apply(B b);
}
```

I have some `Policy` implementations that only work with a specific derived class:

```
class DerivedPolicy implements Policy<Derived> {
   public Derived apply(Derived d) {
     return d.foo().bar();
   }
}
```

but others that can work with any implementation

```
class GeneralPolicy implements Policy {
     public Base apply(Base b) {
         return b.foo();
     }
}
```

The above code compiles, but gives warnings about unchecked types in `GeneralPolicy`, which is accurate since `Base` does not have its generic type specified.  The first obvious fix is `GeneralPolicy implements Policy<Base>`, w

```
Test.java:26: error: type argument Base is not within bounds of type-variable B
class GeneralPolicy implements Policy<Base> {
                                      ^
  where B is a type-variable:
    B extends Base<B> declared in interface Policy
```

Using `GeneralPolicy implements Policy<Base<?>>` also does not work:

```
Test.java:26: error: type argument Base<?> is not within bounds of type-variable B
class GeneralPolicy implements Policy<Base<?>> {
                                          ^
  where B is a type-variable:
    B extends Base<B> declared in interface Policy
```

I made one last try: `GeneralPolicy implements Policy<Base<? extends Base<?>>>`

```
Test.java:26: error: type argument Base<? extends Base<?>> is not within bounds of type-variable B
class GeneralPolicy implements Policy<Base<? extends Base<?->- {
                                           ^
  where B is a type-variable:
    B extends Base<B> declared in interface Policy
```

Is there a way to declare this that works and does not have unchecked types?

Comment: I am pretty sure this could have been an asked in a less confusing way :)

Comment: I think you might need to rethink your wider approach to this problem, as my gut says there might be a simpler solution that doesn't break generics.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 5+ return type could be [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type), so you don't need to use generics, at the beginning you have:

```
interface Base {
    Base foo();
}
class Derived implements Base {
    public Derived foo() { ... }
    public Derived bar() { ... }
}
```

then I don't see a problem with generics anymore.